# launcher icon was not insert in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[pubspec.yaml](https://easyupload.io/lh1czc) detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 18, column 28: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?   ╷
18 │      flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"
```

Comment: add pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: full file not upload some error show

Comment: spacing is important make  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3" in line of flutter and also add this under dependencies not under dev_dependencies.

Comment: where is spacing in dependencies you can put this line

Comment: ^0.7.3 double quotes are not valid just remove it.

Comment: remove double quote but same error was detect

Comment: i edit your question can you try that?

Comment: Add 0.7.0 insted of 0.7.3 I use 0.7.0 it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

your approach should be this:

`dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"`

not This :

`dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
    flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"   <- In this line`

Comment: in read me file it shows under dev_dependencies. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons#-readme-tab-

Comment: Use as a library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons#-installing-tab-

Answer (score 0):

I can't see 18 lines here in your codes, so can't say about the exact issue, but in my suggestion you can use the dependency like `flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5`

I have use my codes like this,

```
dev_dependencies:
  image: ^2.1.14
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.

  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5
```

I have also added `image:^2.1.14` dependency also

Although I don't know its importance you can also try this